# find $t$ let $A+tB$ positive semidefinite

Tags: convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite

Given matrix $A$ is symmetric and positive definite and $B$ is symmetric and NOT positive definite, how to find a positive scalar $t$ so that
$$ A+tB \succeq 0 $$
It is said that it's equivalent to let all eigenvalues of $A+tB $ lie outside the interval $(0,t)$

How to solve this problem algebraically or numerically?

Comment: Is it possible to find $t$ when $A=0$?

Comment: It might be helpful to use the property that $A+tB\ge 0$ iff $\langle  Ax+tBx, x\rangle \ge 0$ for all $x$. However, as @geetha290krm hints, it won't always be possible to find a _positive_ $t$.

Comment: If $B$ is positive definite, let $\gamma$ be its least eigenvalue. Then it holds for every $t\ge \|A\|/\gamma$. If $A$ is positive definite, a small enough $t$ works. In the other cases, such $t$ may not exist

Comment: @Exodd thank you very much! could you show how your result is obtained?